# Connection Pool With Cassandra Tomcat

Tags: cassandra, tomcat7

I want to create a cassandra cluster from tomcat's context.xml with port, credentials, contact points(multiple) pooling options, keyspace, withSSL all specified in the tomcat's context.xml. I am new to cassandra with java, so any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me I have downloaded the following driver
http://www.dbschema.com/cassandra-jdbc-driver.html
Put the jars in lib in tomcat
After that you can add the data source simply as you do with MySQL but just with Casandra driver class and url
The values are exist in the site and you can type multiple hosts in the URL as you want
Hth